# What is in ~/.bitmonero/lock.mdb? Is it needed to start syncing from a blockchain backup from another computer?

Tags: synchronization, lmdb, pruning

I plan on using `monerod` only for a couple of weeks a year with --prune-blockchain flag to keep
the blockchain data below 20GB. In the meantime I will be reinstalling the operating system of the PC that `monerod` will be run on.
When starting anew I want my `monerod` to save time on syncing the blockchain as well as to remember previous settings with regard to pruning.

Do I have to backup the entire `lmdb/` directory or just `lmdb/data.mdb`? What is in `~/.bitmonero/lock.mdb`? Is it needed to start syncing from a backup blockchain data from another computer? After starting
anew do I have to run `monero --detach --prune-blockchain` again or is it unnecessary?

Comment: I haven't used pruning, so YMMV.  I'd back up the whole ~/.bitmonero. the extra stuff that isn't the blockhain will be trivial in size, so why not? With a full node, this works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to backup the entire lmdb/ directory or just lmdb/data.mdb?

You may as well backup your whole `~/.bitmonero` folder, to keep your config, logs *and* blockchain.

> What is in ~/.bitmonero/lock.mdb?

It's just a lock file used to control concurrent access. You're presumably going to shut down Monero before backing up so whether you copy this file or not it really won't matter.

> Is it needed to start syncing from a backup blockchain data from another computer?

No.

> After starting anew do I have to run monero --detach --prune-blockchain again or is it unnecessary?

You don't need to use `--prune-blockchain` again. Once your blockchain is pruned it will always be pruned. Whether you use `--detach` or not is up to you.